# Absolute Value and Inequality

Tags: statistics

From lecture notes:

$P(X>8)$

$=P(X-5>3)$

$\le P(|X-5|\ge 3)$

How did the prof go from 2nd step to 3rd step?

Comment: the set of ( all $x$ for which $x-5>3$ ) is a subset of the set of ( all $x$ for which $|x-5|\ge3$ )

Comment: If $A \implies B$ then $P(a) \ge P(B)$ as B can never happen unless A happens as well.  And $x-5 > 3 \implies |x-5| \ge 3$

Answer (score 1):

The events $\{X-5>3\}$ and $\{X-5\leq -3\}$ are disjoint, and their unon is (almost) $\{\lvert X-5\rvert\geq 3\}$.

$\begin{split}\mathsf P(X>8) &= \mathsf P(X>8)+0 \\ &\leq \mathsf P(X-5>3) +\mathsf P(X-5\leq -3)+\mathsf P(X=8)\\&\leq \mathsf P(\lvert X-5\rvert \geq 3)\end{split}$

or more clearly

$\begin{split}\mathsf P(X>8) &\leq \mathsf P(X>8)+(\mathsf P(X\leq 2)+\mathsf P(X=8)) \\ &\leq \mathsf P(X-5>3) +(\mathsf P(X-5\leq -3)+\mathsf P(X-5=3))\\&\leq \mathsf P(\lvert X-5\rvert \geq 3)\\[2ex]\therefore ~\mathsf P(X>8) &\leq \mathsf P(\lvert X-5\rvert\geq 3)\end{split}$

Comment: their union need not be exactly that, if $P(X=8)\not=0$

Comment: Isn't it $P(X\ge 8)+P(X\le 2)=P(|X-5| \ge 3)$ not $P(X\gt 8)+P(X\le 2)$?

Comment: Sure, to be pedantic.  The inequalities still clearly hold.